# Question about using ParallelMap to speed up computations

Tags: programming, number-theory

First; I define two functions:

```
mgppp[n_?EvenQ] /; n > 3 := 
Block[{m = PrimePi[n/2], p}, 
While[! PrimeQ[n - (p = Prime[m])], m--]; p]

dist[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m - mgppp[n])}; d]
```

After evaluating:

```
a = -1; bag = {}; Do[b = dist[n]; 
If[b > a, a = b; AppendTo[bag, {n, b}]], {n, 4, 10^5, 2}]; bag //AbsoluteTiming
```

I get as output:

{3.00469*10^-7, {{4, 0}, {8, 1}, {16, 3}, {44, 9}, {92, 15}, {242, 
   18}, {256, 21}, {272, 27}, {292, 33}, {476, 39}, {530, 42}, {572, 
   45}, {682, 48}, {688, 75}, {1052, 87}, {1808, 93}, {2228, 
   117}, {3382, 120}, {3472, 135}, {3502, 138}, {3562, 168}, {4952, 
   183}, {6194, 210}, {7102, 228}, {10262, 300}, {17008, 333}, {20684,
    369}, {37052, 393}, {45128, 453}, {49552, 525}, {80144, 621}}}

Next, I use ParallelMap in an attempt to get the same result faster:

```
SetSharedVariable[bag]

a = -1; bag = {};

ParallelMap[b = dist[#]; If[b > a, a = b, AppendTo[bag, {#, b}]] &, 
Range[4, 10^5, 2]]; bag
```

but, I get as output: {}

What I'm I missing?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm currently not in a position to debug the code, but I can tell you right now that using a map to do repeated appends to a list is not going to do you many favors. Doing parallel appends to a shared variable is probably going to be even worse.

Comment: Yeah, I would also suggest to set up an `Association` on each kernel and append to that with meaningful keys so that the associations can be joined afterwards. Or using ``Internal`Bag``...

Comment: The following similar example works: t = {}; ParallelMap[If[PrimeQ[2^# - 1], AppendTo[t, #]] &, 
 Range[100]]; t      The ouput is: {2, 13, 19, 31, 3, 17, 5, 7, 61, 89}  I'm not attempting to duplicate Goldbach Partition.  I'm attempting to find how to make the above ParallelMap evaluation work.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit  Notice that the simpler example:
t = {}; ParallelMap[If[PrimeQ[2^# - 1], AppendTo[t, #]] &, Range[100]]; t 
does not incurr into the problems that you are describing.
There are not many examples of ParallelMap to follow available in the help documentation. 

The simple example above suggests that a slight modification of:

SetSharedVariable[bag]

a = -1; bag = {};
ParallelMap[b = dist[#]; If[b > a, a = b, AppendTo[bag, {#, b}]] &, 
Range[4, 10^5, 2]]; bag

will allow this program to append the values {n, dist[n]} to the set "bag".

Comment: I'm not saying it can't work: my point is simply that this is the wrong way to try and improve the speed of your code. Repeated appending is not very efficient in Mathematica. And if you do repeated parellel appends to a shared variable, each subkernel has to communicate often with the master kernel, which is going to make things even slower. I really would encourage you to look for a method where each kernel can work for itself without the need for a shared variable.